# what are benefits of creating tokens for creators

Tags: tokens, gas

What are the benefits of tokens for their creators? and specially gas tokens? (like CHI Gas token or token with infinite supply)
How their prices are determined in the first place?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tokens are commonly used to raise money for a crypto projects at the beginning. Many projects could run without their own token.
2. Gas tokens are used to speculate on the price of gas. If the price of gas is low you can use cheap gas to mint a bunch of gas tokens. Once gas prices are higher you can either sell your gas tokens or use them yourself to reduce the total gas used by certain transactions.
3. Prices are determined by supply and demand. For more details I'd recommend a basic economics introduction on youtube for example.